# Chrome not handling .style = "background-color:#333223;"

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

In the code included below, the script is toggling a div on and off.  The  *.style*
code, controls the background color of the the parent element of the div being toggled
on and off.  The code works in Opera but not in Chrome, and I haven't been able to
research  (search) a solution.

I can of course move on and write other code and achieve what I need, but this has my
curiosity up now.

```
function CheckOutOpn(){
    var Inny = document.getElementById("RightPaneASxOrderForm");
    MVxCheckOutForm();
    CDxButtonOpnChkOut();
    MVxCLOSExBttnChkout();
    Inny.style = "background-color:#332223;";
} 

function CLOSExCheckOut(){
    var Inny = document.getElementById("RightPaneASxOrderForm");
    MVxButtonOpnChkOut();
    CDxCLOSExBttnChkout();
    CDxOrderFormItself();
    Inny.style = "background-color:#33B32E;";
}
```

Comment: Hard to believe this code would work in any browser ...

Comment: @Teemu LOL well, maybe when the fat lady sings and the V8 kills Opera it won't work anymore anywhere.

Comment: Maybe it really was possible ... I've uninstalled Opera for a long time ago : ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using:

```
Inny.style.backgroundColor = "#332223";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style

> ... Except in Opera, styles can not be set by assigning a string to the
>   (read only) style property, as in elt.style = "color: blue;". This is
>   because the style attribute returns a  CSSStyleDeclaration object.

Comment: Right, so Opera is sorta the odd man out then, hmm. In anyCase, got it.  Should be using CamelCase.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the style of an element textually, you need to use either

```
Inny.style.cssText="background-color:#33B32E"
```

or

```
Inny.setAttribute("style","background-color:#33B32E")
```

or you can set the properties directly:

```
Inny.style.backgroundColor = "#33B32E";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you fine. only mistake you are doing is, when you are adding the css properties to the element.

```
function CheckOutOpn(){
    var Inny = document.getElementById("RightPaneASxOrderForm");
    MVxCheckOutForm();
    CDxButtonOpnChkOut();
    MVxCLOSExBttnChkout();
    Inny.style.backgroundColor = "#332223";
}
```